# Roboto calendar library

Tags: android, calendar

I am using this library  [Roboto Calendar Library](https://github.com/marcohc/RobotoCalendarView) to do my own calendar but I don´t know how use it, I am trying to mark a day on my calendar like this:

```
if(currentMonthIndex==2){
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());

            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 8);

            robotoCalendarView.markDayWithStyle(RobotoCalendarView.GREEN_CIRCLE, calendar.getTime());

        }
```

but the marked day when I run it is not 8, is 18 and I don´t know why, some help? Thanks

Comment: This is an open source library that is not widely known yet, you need to read the README.md and look at the example: https://github.com/marcohc/RobotoCalendarView/blob/master/RobotoCalendarSample/src/com/disegnator/robotocalendarsample/MainActivity.java.

Comment: I have seen the example but in this example he marks some random days , he not marks a single day

Comment: Please post your complete code here

Answer (score 0):

I use this function:

```
robotoCalendarView.markCircleImage1(calendar);
```

But, first of all, ensure that you have defined the color in your `colors.xml`:

```
<color name="roboto_calendar_circle_1">#12ca25</color>
```